# C++ vector remove_if pairs

Tags: c++, data-structures, stdvector

Im trying to remove pairs from vector with remove_if, but im getting errors

```
bool MyClass::isSingleTag(const pair<int,string> & val) {
   string tag = val.second;
   int posImg, posBr;
   posImg = tag.find("<img");
   posBr = tag.find("<br");
   if (posImg == -1 && posBr == -1) {
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
void MyClass::deleteSingleTags() {
   vector<pair<int,string>>::iterator last_iter;
   last_iter = remove_if(allTags.begin(), allTags.end(), &MyClass::isSingleTag);
   allTags.erase(last_iter, allTags.end());
}
```

Errors: http://pastebin.com/1FCWRVDG

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: His error is that he's trying to pass a PTMF as the predicate.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that `isSingleTag` is not declared `static` and therefore doesn't work as a predicate for `remove_if`.

Comment: You don't show the declaration - is `isSingleTag` static?

Comment: Hi vegazz! The information you've provided here isn't enough for us to help diagnose what's wrong. Can you provide more information, like what specific error you're getting (compile-time error? if so, what? runtime error? if so, what kind?) or enough code for us to be able to reproduce the error on our end? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer to a member function isn't callable without an object of the class the function is member of.

Make `isSingleTag` `static` - taking its address results in a plain function pointer. Alternatively, make it a free function, since it looks like it's got no bussiness being a member function in the first place (it doesn't access any other members, does it?).

The other option (for when you legitimately need to be a member function) is to bind it to a class object, using `std::bind`:

```
MyClass obj;
auto func = std::bind(&MyClass::isSingleTag, obj);
```

Now func is a callable that you can pass to the algorithm.